# Simple user sessions in node.js

Tags: node.js, session

I'm currently making a simple login system in node.js, at the moment, the main problem is that a user can access the "homepage" without first logging in. I want to stop this, and I'm pretty sure creating user sessions is the answer.

I've tried using express-sessions, for example, when the user successfully logs in, this line is called:

```
req.session.email = email //sets the session email to the entered email
```

Then, the user is redirected to the homepage where it checks:

```
if (req.session.email == undefined){
    res.send("You must login first!") //res.send() for simple functionality
}
```

However, I feel like the "session" I am creating is universal, and every connection to the server will already have an email defined if someone has already done it. EG, Jeff logs in and is successfully redirected to the homepage, if John then types "website.com/homepage" it will connect because the `req.session.email` has already been set by Jeff.

Am I going completely the wrong direction with this?

Comment: I think you might be confused... Sessions are unique to requests, thus the session created by John will be different from Jeff.

Comment: Maybe I am, so would this work in theory? I think I'm misusing the word session.

Comment: It will work in theory, but not very secure.

Comment: @Gary Perhaps if I use a session ID generated from the email, instead of the email itself, would this more secure? Or is that not the issue.

Comment: There are a lot of ways to do it by passing a token.  Take a look at https://github.com/scotch-io/node-token-authentication, it will give you some ideas on how to handle